# How to add shimmer effect to imageview in android?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I need to add [Shimmer effect](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/shimmer-android/master/shimmer.gif) to image view as given in the link for my ImageView. The animation should be from bottom to top instead of left to right as in the sample picture. I have tried the [facebook shimmer libraby](https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android) but it supports from API 16 above only. I need to support if from 14 above. I have also tried [this library](https://github.com/RomainPiel/Shimmer-android) but it doesn't have support for ImageViews as well as bottom to top animation. Is there any library to achieve the shimmer effect for an Imageview (with bottom to top animation)? or is there any way to implement this feature using ImageView?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own custom view!

```
class ShimmerView : View, ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener{

constructor(context: Context)
        : super(context) { init() }

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet)
        : super(context, attrs) { init() }

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int)
        : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) { init() }


companion object {
    const val EDGE_ALPHA      = 12
    const val SHADER_COLOR_R  = 170
    const val SHADER_COLOR_G  = 170
    const val SHADER_COLOR_B  = 170
    const val CENTER_ALPHA    = 100
    const val ITEM_BG_COLOR   = Color.WHITE

    val EDGE_COLOR   = Color.argb(EDGE_ALPHA, SHADER_COLOR_R, SHADER_COLOR_G, SHADER_COLOR_B)
    val CENTER_COLOR = Color.argb(CENTER_ALPHA, SHADER_COLOR_R, SHADER_COLOR_G, SHADER_COLOR_B)

    const val LIST_ITEM_LINES    = 3
    const val CORNER_RADIUS      = 2
    const val LINE_HEIGHT        = 15
    const val H_SPACING          = 12
    const val W_SPACING          = 16
    const val IMAGE_SIZE         = 50
    const val ANIMATION_DURATION = 1500L
}


private var listItems:    Bitmap?        = null
private var animator:     ValueAnimator? = null
private var paint:        Paint?         = null
private var shaderPaint:  Paint?         = null
private var shaderColors: IntArray?      = null

private var lineHeight:   Float = 0F
private var hSpacing:     Float = 0F
private var wSpacing:     Float = 0F
private var imageSize:    Float = 0F
private var cornerRadius: Float = 0F


// 1. Инициализируем переменные.
// 1. Initialize variables.
fun init() {
    val metric = context.resources.displayMetrics
    cornerRadius    = dpToPixels(metric, CORNER_RADIUS)
    hSpacing        = dpToPixels(metric, H_SPACING)
    wSpacing        = dpToPixels(metric, W_SPACING)
    lineHeight      = spToPixels(metric, LINE_HEIGHT)
    imageSize       = dpToPixels(metric, IMAGE_SIZE)

    animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(-1F, 2F)
    animator?.duration     = ANIMATION_DURATION
    animator?.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    animator?.repeatCount  = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
    animator?.addUpdateListener(this)

    paint = Paint()

    shaderPaint = Paint()
    shaderPaint?.isAntiAlias = true
    shaderColors = intArrayOf(EDGE_COLOR, CENTER_COLOR, EDGE_COLOR)
}


// 2. Когда View отобразилась на экране, запускаем анимацию.
// 2. When View is displayed on the screen, run the animation.
override fun onVisibilityChanged(changedView: View?, visibility: Int) {
    super.onVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility)
    when(visibility) {
        VISIBLE         -> animator?.start()
        INVISIBLE, GONE -> animator?.cancel()
    }
}


// 3. При выполнении анимации, изменяем положение шейдера и перерисовываем View.
// 3. When the animation, change the position of the shader and redraw View.
override fun onAnimationUpdate(valueAnimator: ValueAnimator) {
    if(isAttachedToWindow) {
        val factor: Float = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Float
        updateShader(width = width.toFloat(), factor = factor)
        invalidate()
    }
}


// 4. Одновременно со стартом анимации, рисуем элементы.
// 4. Simultaneously with the start of the animation, draw the elements.
override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
    updateShader(width = w.toFloat())
    if (h > 0 && w > 0) {
        drawListItems(w, h)
    } else {
        listItems = null
        animator?.cancel()
    }
}


private fun updateShader(width: Float, factor: Float = -1F) {
    val left = width * factor
    val shader = LinearGradient(
            left, 0F, left+width, 0F, shaderColors, floatArrayOf(0f, 0.5f, 1f), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP)
    shaderPaint?.shader = shader

}


override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(EDGE_COLOR)
    canvas.drawRect(0F, 0F, canvas.width.toFloat(), canvas.height.toFloat(), shaderPaint)
    if (listItems != null) { canvas.drawBitmap(listItems, 0F, 0F, paint) }
}


private fun drawListItems(w: Int, h: Int) {
    listItems  = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(listItems)
    val item   = getItemBitmap(w)
    var top    = 0

    do {
        canvas.drawBitmap(item, 0F, top.toFloat(), paint)
        top += item.height
    } while (top < canvas.height)

    canvas.drawColor(ITEM_BG_COLOR, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
}


private fun getItemBitmap(w: Int): Bitmap {
    val h    = calculateListItemHeight(LIST_ITEM_LINES)
    val item = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8)

    val canvas = Canvas(item)
    canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0))

    val itemPaint = Paint()
    itemPaint.isAntiAlias = true
    itemPaint.color       = Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0)
    itemPaint.xfermode    = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN)

    //Avatar
    val rectF = RectF(wSpacing, hSpacing, wSpacing+imageSize, hSpacing+imageSize)
    canvas.drawOval(rectF, itemPaint)

    val textLeft  = rectF.right  + hSpacing
    val textRight = canvas.width - wSpacing

    //Title line
    val titleWidth = (textRight - textLeft)*0.5F
    rectF.set(textLeft, hSpacing, textLeft+titleWidth, hSpacing+lineHeight)
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, itemPaint)

    //Time stamp
    val timeWidth = (textRight - textLeft)*0.2F
    rectF.set(textRight-timeWidth, hSpacing, textRight, hSpacing+lineHeight)
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, itemPaint)

    //Text lines
    for (i in 0..LIST_ITEM_LINES-1) {
        val lineTop = rectF.bottom + hSpacing
        rectF.set(textLeft, lineTop, textRight, lineTop+lineHeight)
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, itemPaint)
    }

    return item
}


private fun calculateListItemHeight(lines: Int): Int {
    return ((lines*lineHeight) + (hSpacing*(lines+1))).toInt()
}


private fun dpToPixels(metrics: DisplayMetrics, dp: Int): Float {
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp.toFloat(), metrics)
}


private fun spToPixels(metrics: DisplayMetrics, sp: Int): Float {
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, sp.toFloat(), metrics)
}


override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow()
    animator?.removeAllUpdateListeners()
    animator  = null
    listItems = null
}
```

}

[Source](https://github.com/pasha656/CustomView)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Shimmer Library does support API level 14. I am using it in a project with these settings:

```
 defaultConfig {
      ....
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
      ....
    }
```

With this dependency:

```
dependencies {
     ....
    compile 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0'
}
```